# Query for 2 indices in Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm wondering if it's possible to query for 2 indicies in Elasticsearch, and display the results mixed together in 1 table. For example:

Indicies:

```
food-american-burger
food-italian-pizza
food-japanese-ramen
food-mexican-burritos

#query here for burger and pizza, and display the results in a csv file
#i.e. if there was a timestamp field, display results starting from the most recent
```

I know you can do a query for food-*, but it would give 2 indices that I wouldn't want.

I looked up the multisearch module for Elasticsearch DSL, but the documentation shows only an instance of 1 index query:

```
ms = MultiSearch(index='blogs')

ms = ms.add(Search().filter('term', tags='python'))
ms = ms.add(Search().filter('term', tags='elasticsearch'))
```

Part 1:

Is it possible to use this for multiple indices? Ultimately, I would like to query for x number of indicies and display all the data in a single human-readable format (csv, json, etc.), but I'm not sure how to perform a single query for only the indices I want.

I currently have the functionality to perform queries and write out the data, but each data file would only consist of that index I queried for. I would like to display all the data into one file.

Part 2:

The data is stored in a dictionary, and then I am writing it to a csv. It is currently being ordered by timestamp. The code:

```
sorted_rows = sorted(rows,key=lambda x: x['@timestamp'], reverse=True)
for row in sorted_rows:
          writer.writerow(row.values())
```

When writing to the csv, the timestamp field is not the first column. I'm storing the fields in a dictionary, and updating that dictionary for every Elasticsearch hit, then writing it to the csv. Is there a way to move the timestamp field to the first column?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html comma separated index names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Elasticsearch Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html), you can query a single index (e.g. `food-american-burger`), multiple comma-separated indicies (e.g. `food-american-burger,food-italian-pizza`), or all indicies using the `_all` keyword.

I haven't personally used the Python client, but this is an API convention and should apply to any of the official Elasticsearch clients.

---

For part 2, you should probably submit a separate question to keep things to a single topic per question, since the two topics are not directly related.